# How to align li to the center with the dot

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am trying to center align the li the tag and the dot and here is my tried code and i have used all the methods but i am unable to find any solution.

```html
<div class="mdc-layout-grid">
  <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
    <div
      class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-6-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet"
    >
      <img
        src="./assets/images/group.png"
        style="display: block; margin: auto"
        class="images"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      class="mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-6-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet"
    >
      <div>
        <h2 style="text-align: center">staff</h2>
        <ul style="list-style-position: inside; justify-items: center">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this with material design or plain CSS? It looks like you're using some material design related dependency. Could you include that in your code sample as well?

Comment: @konekoya no i am not using any material design component i am using the material for the layout grid only and i want to achieve using normal css

Comment: You can then provide these deps info in your sample code. It's even better if you could provide a reproducible example, something like codepen or codesanbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the ul with a div and try the following code.

```
<style>
.box{
  display: flex;
}

.box ul{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div>
  <h2 style="text-align: center">staff</h2>
  <div class="box"> 
     <ul style="list-style-position: inside; justify-items: center">
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
        <li>list 3</li>
        <li>list 4</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `align:center` to put your `li` in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ul style="list-style-position: inside;text-align: center;">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center all the "li" elements of your "ul", including li "dots" of it, try putting into the "div" parent:

```
<div style= "display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"**>
        <h2 style="text-align: center">staff</h2>
        <ul style="list-style-position: inside; justify-items: center">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `text-align: center` on the parent `ul` element, this should center the child `li` elements for you.